# DBT Snapshot specify runtime timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Is it possible to specify when a snapshot "update" is being run? I have an airflow dag that I want to re-run and it correctly creates the snapshot with historical data.

The problem is that the `DBT_VALID_TO` AND `DBT_VALID_FROM` columns are all today.

Comment: I found the following solution which works for me. But I feel like there should be a simpler solution? https://gist.github.com/jeremyyeo/7da6a6a4fd6dba598c04c431f74e91c0#file-build_snapshot_table-sql

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the `strategy` for your snapshot. If you use a `timestamp` strategy, dbt will use the `updated_at` timestamp for the `valid_from` date for the most recent records. If you use `check_cols`, then dbt has no way of knowing when the changes were made, so it uses the current timestamp.

Comment: To clarify, if I re-run the transform as if it was done in the past; I want it to use that time stamp. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but how would that work, exactly? A snapshot captures the current state of a mutating dataset -- how would you reconstruct that past state? Snapshots are unique among dbt operations because they are not idempotent nor re-creatable. A Snapshot creates new data that you need to backup/protect like source data